# How to implement NSUndoManager and arrays in iOS using Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, nsundomanager

So quick question. I am writing an iOS app for a dart game. And I am trying to implement an undo button to undo the last action.

Whats going on: When you push any of the buttons they add that amount to the score. The users score that the buttons have an effect on is the currentPlayer. 
I want the undo button to undo whatever button was pushed last. I have been researching and it seems like they are all showing how to hard code an undo action. However it could be any of the 6 buttons hit_single, hit_double, attack_double... etc.

FIRST: I don't know how to use undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(target:AnyObject, selector: Selector, object: AnyObject?), I'm not sure how to apply this and what each of these 3 things do.

SECOND: In my game you have to go from 1-20(the numbers on a dart board) and then hit bullseye to win. The variables user1score and user2score increase their count to display what number the player is aiming at. However, after 20 I want the score to display "Bullseye". I am not sure if there is a way to write a mixed content array, one that allows counting 1-20, and then the 20th array value say "Bullseye". Or maybe write an If statement that says if the user1score/user2score is greater than 20 print "Bullseye". The problem is it says its an integer and I cant input a string value.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Galaxy_VC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var currentPlayerName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var user1score: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var user2score: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var darts_Thrown: UILabel!

var names = ["Big Meat", "J Hooks"]

var currentPlayer = 0

var scores = [0, 0]

var count = 0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupGame()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setupGame() {
    user1score.text = "\(count)"
    user2score.text = "\(count)"
}


func updateTurn() {
    currentPlayerName.text = names[currentPlayer]
    user1score.text = "\(scores[0])"
    user2score.text = "\(scores[1])"
}

func undoLast(score: NSNumber) {
    undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, handler: <#T##AnyObject -> ()#>)
}

@IBAction func btn_NextTurn(sender: UIButton) {
    currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func btn_UndoTurn(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func hit_Single(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[currentPlayer] + 1
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func hit_Double(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[currentPlayer] + 2
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func hit_Triple(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[currentPlayer] + 3
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func Miss(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[currentPlayer] - 1
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func attack_double(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[1 - currentPlayer] - 2
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func attack_Triple(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[1 - currentPlayer] - 3
    updateTurn()
}
}
```

Any help you can provide would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this? http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/

Comment: Daniel I have, that was what I meant by I dont know which things I would enter to apply it to mine. I dont know if it is recreating scores and it is losing me can you help break this down for me on how I would apply it to my code? 'func updateScore(score: NSNumber) {
    undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector:Selector("updateScore:"), object:myMovie.score)
    undoManager.setActionName(NSLocalizedString("actions.update", comment: "Update Score"))
    myMovie.score = score
}
'

Comment: hey, Cornwellington you solved it or not, I have the same issue like u.???? I don't know how to do, so if u solved it than guide me.